# Вопрос по tableView + CoreData в Swift 3

Tags: xcode, swift, mobile-development

Добрый день! Имеется простое приложение:

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {


    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!


    @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!

    var array: [Data] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return array.count
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = UITableViewCell()

    let task = array[indexPath.row]

     cell.textLabel?.text = task.data


        return cell


    }

    @IBAction func addButton(_ sender: AnyObject) {

    let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext



        let task = Data(context: context)

        task.data = textField.text!

    (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).saveContext()

    }

    @IBOutlet weak var getButton: UIButton!

    @IBAction func getButton(_ sender: AnyObject) {

let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext

        do {
            array = try context.fetch(Data.fetchRequest()) } catch {

                print("fsfsa")}

    tableView.reloadData()
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext

        if editingStyle == .delete {

        let task = array[indexPath.row]

        context.delete(task)

        (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).saveContext()

            do {
                array = try context.fetch(Data.fetchRequest()) } catch {

                    print("fsfsa")}

            tableView.reloadData()

        }
    }
}
```

Проблема в том, что при нажатии кнопки get в tableView, по какой-то причине выводится 2 одинаковые строки! То, есть, если в поле textField я введу test, нажму кнопку Save, после сделаю запрос посреством кнопки Get, в tableView выведется строка test в 2х ячейках! Почему, я не понимаю. Уже 5 раз проверил код (насколько мне позволяет навык). Еще хотелось бы что бы новая строка писалась вверху, и старые, соответственно опускались вниз. Если подскажите, как делать, буду благодарен!

Comment: Разобрался я почему 2 строки записывается. При выполнение функции getButton, второй раз срабатывает функция addButton. Почему, не знаю. Про отображения нового текса в нижних ячейках вопрос остался.

Comment: Copy-Paste - вот скорее всего причина ваших бед. Вы взяли кнопку addButton в IB, скопировали и сделали из нее кнопку get. Если так и было, то идите в IB, и там отключите кнопку от лишнего эвента, так как скорее всего у вас их там два.

Comment: Честно, сложно понять чего ты хочешь добиться. Но вот это однозначно поможет - https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/CreatingObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001075-CH5-SW1

Answer (score 0):

Или просто стирай содержимое в textField после нажати на addButton 
Потом при сохранении проверяй на пустую строку то-есть не давай ему сохранять если пустая строка .

Comment: Добро пожаловать на stackoverflow! У нас принято давать более подробные ответы. В вашем случае лучше привести пример кода.